# Creating a new Shared Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I run the code below, which is taken from: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives#python

```
# Create a new drive
        test_drive_metadata = {'name': 'Test Drive'}
        request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        test_drive = self.service.drives().create(
            body=test_drive_metadata,
            requestId=request_id,
            fields='id'
        ).execute()
```

I get "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file." This does not happen if I create files, if I list shared drives or anything else. There are no other required scopes other than ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'].

It should be noted that I am using a service account. Are service accounts not allowed to create shared drives? This is not documented anywhere as far as I am aware if this is the case.

Comment: Just to note, I also just tried by updating the service accounts API client access from my G Suite admin, as well as in the app, to include 
SCOPES = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'
        ]
but this does not work either...

Comment: It does work if I do the following: self.credentials = self.credentials.with_subject('<my G-Suite email>). So there are no ways to create a drive with a service account?

Comment: A service account should be able to create a shared drive on its on drive account.

Comment: @DaImTo yes, I would have thought so. But are there any specific permissions it must be given? For now I'll have to continue development whereby the service account mimics a G Suite business user.

Comment: well if you are using domain wide delegation then the user you are delegating as needs to have permission to create the shared drive.

Comment: @DaImTo Ye, there are no problems when creating a shared drive when delegated to a user with permissions. The problem is that it doesn't let me create a shared drive as the service account without delegating to another user. The service account doesn't have permissions to do so itself.

Comment: I woulder if you can add the service account as a user in the gsuit admin.   Its been a while since i have had access to a gsuite account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any explicit documentation regarding this limitation, but considering that Service Accounts (without using DWD and impersonation) are supposed to manage **application data, and not user data**, it makes sense that they cannot be used to manage data that is shared with regular users.

Also, the use of Service Accounts to manage shared documents seems to be advised against, according to [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority):

> Using the service account as a common owner to create many shared documents can have severe performance implications.

On the other hand, since Service Accounts have certain limitations compared to regular accounts (for example, Event creation in Calendar), this could probably be one of these limitations.

In any case, in order to make sure that's the case, I'd suggest you to **report this behaviour in [this Issue Tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191650)**.

#### Reference:

- [Drive API: Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

Comment: That link appears to be for the Calendar Component? Should it not be for the drive? https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191650/manage#basic

Comment: @ev350 Yes, you're right, thank you for pointing that out. I don't know what I was thinking...